# Highcharts Zones not working with valid JSON

Tags: highcharts

Trying to replicate this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-dashstyle-dot

It works fine when I directly copy and paste, but when I'm using the getJSON function, the line will populate, but its not recognizing the dashed line for the zone.

```
[{"name":"Test","data":[29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],"zoneAxis":"x","zones":"[{value: 8}, {dashStyle: 'dot'}]"}]
```

Seems to be in valid JSON format - so not sure what the issue is and I'm not getting any sort of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should be formatted as a JSON within a JSON to actually work - inception?

```
[{"name":"Test","data":[29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],"zoneAxis":"x","zones":[{"value": "8"}, {"dashStyle": "dot"}]}]
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it's just a nested JSON object. The value of the zones property is an object, not a string, and should be passed as such, is all. A thing can be in a perfectly "valid" JSON format without being in the correct format for the use at hand.

Answer (score 0):

"zones":"[{value: 8}, {dashStyle: 'dot'}]" - remove the quotes from the value. So try [{value: 8}, {dashStyle: 'dot'}]